# Parse Seats from PokerStars History

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
Seat 6: Dizzy (€26.49 in chips)
```

I would like to parse the seatNumber (6), the screenName of the player (Dizzy), and the stack (26.49). Is it possible with only one regex ?

Here was my try:

```
    Seat.([0-9]) 
    :
    .   //Space
    ([^(]*)  //screenName (everything but the next opening parenthesis)
    \(
    [^0-9]+ // the euro or dollar sign
    ([0-9\.]+) // the stack
    .in.chips
```

But obviously it doesn't work if the screenName has a parenthesis, for example with :

```
Seat 3: padre(93) (€10.52 in chips)
```

Comment: Can screen names have spaces? If not, swap out the `(` for `\s`.

Comment: yep they can have some spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "screenName" section needs to be adjusted from:

```
([^(]*)
```

To:

```
(.*)
```

Quantifiers are greedy by default -- they will match as much as possible, while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.  In this case you want to match everything up to the *last* `(` character.

Modifying the pattern this way will cause the `.*` pattern to match everything up to the end of the string, but the regex engine will notice that this causes the pattern to fail to match.  It will then *backtrack* up to the last `(`, where the rest of the pattern will match.

See [this test](http://fiddle.re/qxeza) for an illustration of how this modification would affect matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that but this reminder will help me remembering the trick forever :-)

Answer (score 2):

First off `.` doesn't mean 'space', it means *any* character whatsoever. Using `.` when you really mean space can lead to some unexpected results. I'd recommend something like this:

```
Seat
\s+          // one or more whitespace characters
(\d+)        // one or more digits
:            // colon
\s+          // one or more whitespace characters
(.+?)        // one or more of any characters, non-greedily
\s+          // one or more whitespace characters
\(           // open paren
[€$]         // the euro or dollar sign
(\d+\.\d+)   // the stack
\s+          // one or more whitespace characters
in chips     // literal 'in chips'
\)           // close paren
```

You *may* also want to put start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around this as well. In the end your pattern would look like this:

```
/^Seat\s+(\d+):\s+(.+?)\s+\([€$]\d+\.\d+)\s+in chips\)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know what variations your looking at.
This is one avenue you may take -

```
 Seat
 [^\S\n]+                     

 ( [0-9]+ )                   // seat number
 : [^\S\n]+                   

 ( .+ )                       // screenName
 [^\S\n]+                     

 \(
 [^\S\n]* 

 [^0-9.]+                     // dollar
 ( [0-9.]+ )                  // the stack

 [^\S\n]+ in [^\S\n]+ chips [^\S\n]*    
 \)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Seat\s([0-9]+):\s(.+)\s\(.([0-9.]+)\s
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/79XjNt8LPTaE_Rgq)

if you want to match that exact string completely from end to end.

```
^Seat\s([0-9]+):\s(.+)\s\(.([0-9.]+)\sin\schips\)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/ii4bgN8Sojq3qErD)

I decided to put a "." for the euro money sign just in case the currency changes to dollars or something else it will still work. Not sure if this is what you wanted but here :).